# Load bitmap from SD card don't work

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap

I have some problem show images from sd card, i try to load bitmap into imageview.

This is the code to load image:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 8;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

File imagen1 = new File(ruta + contratoActual.getImgDoc1());
    if (imagen1.exists()) {
        try {

        bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(imagen1), null, options);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        decoded[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }
```

load bitmap into image view:

```
    LayoutParams p = (LayoutParams) img1.getLayoutParams();
    p.width = 250;
    p.height = 190;

    if (result[0] != null) {
    img1.setImageBitmap(result[0]);
    img1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    img1.setLayoutParams(p);
    result[0].recycle();
    }
```

and here show the result:

[image: black image]

and i have this log result:

[image: error]

Comment: Can you show the part of code where you load bitmap to `ImageView` ?

Comment: The code:

       LayoutParams p = (LayoutParams) img1.getLayoutParams();
     p.width = 250;
     p.height = 190;

     if (result[0] != null) {
  if (result[0].isRecycled()) {
      Log.e("Reciclado", "Sereciclo[0]");
  }
  img1.setImageBitmap(result[0]);
  img1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
  img1.setLayoutParams(p);
  result[0].recycle();
     }

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap YourBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(YourImagePath, options);
```

[Example](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/09/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html)

File Read Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I find the error on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109555/android-message-cannot-generate-texture-from-bitmap

recycle bitmap is the reason of the black image. delete them and works fine