# Reading a bitmap from sdcard

Tags: android, bitmap, sd-card

I saved a bitmap file in the SDcard through the crop intent and I would like to read it in another activity. However, I keep getting following run time error : Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/sdcard/oc.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/ReadFile: Bitmap must be non-null

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/oc.jpg");
//save output image in uri
cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
```

Reading the same file in another activity:

```
Bitmap image4 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file:///sdcard/oc.jpg");
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246972/load-bitmap-from-sd-card-dont-work) but it did not work and I got the same run time error.

Comment: "I saved a bitmap file in the SDcard through the crop intent" -- [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). "Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/sdcard/oc.jpg" -- do not hardcode paths (use methods, like `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`), and make sure that you have the appropriate permissions (including runtime permissions).

Comment: I tried String imageInSD =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"oc.jpg";
         image4 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD); but Still I get failed to read bitmap and  I included the run time permission

Comment: `....getAbsolutePath() +"oc.jpg"` That should be `.getAbsolutePath() +"/oc.jpg"`

Comment: `decodeFile("file:///sdcard/oc.jpg");` That should have been `decodeFile("/sdcard/oc.jpg");` if you want to use a hard coded path which is ok during tests.

Comment: @greenapp yes I forget the /, but even with it does not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write to external storage, make sure you added the permission:

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
```

Checks if external storage is available for read and write

```
    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Use the root of the public directory instead of using the root of Android.

If you want to save public files on the external storage, use the getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()

```
    public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) {
    // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory. 
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), albumName);
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
    }
    return file;
}
```

If you want to save files that are private to your app, use the getExternalFilesDir()

```
    public File getAlbumStorageDir(Context context, String albumName) {
    // Get the directory for the app's private pictures directory. 
    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), albumName);
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Directory not created");
    }
    return file;
}
```

and I forgot to mention:

`decodeFile` **expects a path**